# mysql connectoin through angularjs

Tags: mysql, angularjs

I need to select data from a mysql database and handle it with angularjs. I have a database with a table called "mapas". The columns are id, lat and lng. lat and lng are strings that stores coordinates. Someone can teach me how to select lat and lng from the database and store it on a variable with angularjs? I'll always have only one line on the table. Would be nice to get the data in a json like this: {"lat": "-21.2292703", "lng": "-44.9775718"}

uploading a file i handle it like this:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function ($event) {
        var files = $event.target.files;
        var jsonCoords;

        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {

            jsonCoords = JSON.parse(event.target.result);

            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(jsonCoords.lat, jsonCoords.lng),
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

            document.getElementById("formJsonFile").reset();

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(jsonCoords.lat, jsonCoords.lng),
                map: map,
                title: 'Coordenada: ' + jsonCoords.lat + ',' + jsonCoords.lng
            });
        }
        reader.readAsText(file)

    };
```

Selecting from mysql i would do the same thing, but the coords would come from the select.

Thank you

Comment: why don't you do it with a server-side programming language? angular is just a client-side framework

Comment: how? can you help me?

Comment: you have to choose a server-side programming language first. i.e php , nodejs , ASP.net and ..., then implement services which handles you data and connection to database. you can't do DB directly from client-side framework